# Android ConnectionService - SecurityException when registering phone account

Tags: android

I'm trying to implement [ConnectionService](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telecom/ConnectionService.html). For this I need to register a phone account on TelecomService, so the device will know it can use my app for making phone calls.

When I try to register a phone account I get a SecurityException: Package com.xxx.xxx does not belong to 10145.

What am I missing? Here is the code to register a phone account. (I have added the permission to the manifest etc)

```
PhoneAccountHandle   phoneAccountHandle = new PhoneAccountHandle(new ComponentName("com.mypackage", "com.mypackage.MyConnectionService", "my_phoneHandleId");
PhoneAccount.Builder builder            = PhoneAccount.builder(phoneAccountHandle, "Custom label");

builder.setCapabilities(PhoneAccount.CAPABILITY_CALL_SUBJECT | PhoneAccount.CAPABILITY_CONNECTION_MANAGER);
builder.addSupportedUriScheme("my_scheme");
builder.setAddress(Uri.parse("my_scheme://" + "customNumber"));

PhoneAccount phoneAccount = builder.build();
telecomService.registerPhoneAccount(phoneAccount);
```

Comment: Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40461292/i-need-help-to-get-cnapcallerdisplayname-in-android/42948594#42948594

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you forgot to declare permission:

```
android:permission="android.permission.BIND_TELECOM_CONNECTION_SERVICE"
```

And take care to request this permission for Marshmellow and higher android version. [Requesting Permissions at Run Time](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html)

```
    // Here, thisActivity is the current activity
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(thisActivity,
                Manifest.permission.BIND_TELECOM_CONNECTION_SERVICE)
        != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

    // Should we show an explanation?
    if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(thisActivity,
            Manifest.permission.BIND_TELECOM_CONNECTION_SERVICE)) {

        // Show an expanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
        // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
        // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.

    } else {

        // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.

        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(thisActivity,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.BIND_TELECOM_CONNECTION_SERVICE},
                MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_BIND_TELECOM_CONNECTION_SERVICE);

        // MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_BIND_TELECOM_CONNECTION_SERVICE is an
        // app-defined int constant. The callback method gets the
        // result of the request.
    }
}
```

Comment: I already had the permission in Android.manifest. I tried the code for requesting permission, I always get permission denied in the callback though. With no dialog presented to the user. Not sure what I'm doing wrong. I had targetsdk set to 15, tried with setting it to 23, but same result.

Comment: did you find a solution? i am stuck with the same problem

Comment: Are you able to find the solution for it , I also stuck in same place not able to grant permission through code

Comment: @RasmusHöglund I am also stuck with same problem. Did you find any solution?

Comment: @Sonal  did you got any solutions?

Comment: @KAMAL did you got any solutions